# Looping with an specific step in a long datetime string in bash

Tags: bash, loops, date

I have a list of files with the substring YYYYMMDDHH in them (example: 2016112200 means 2016 November 22th at 00 hours). These files are: `temp_2016102200.data`, `temp_2016102212.data`, `temp_2016102300.data`, `temp_2016102312.data`, ..., `temp_20170301.data`. **And** I also have other family of files substituting `temp` by `wind`.

For each string YYYYMMDDHH I want to create a tar with the `temp` and its correspondent `wind` file. I don't want this process to stop if one or both files are missing.

My idea was to loop from 12 hours to 12 hours, but I am having some problems because to specify the date I did: `b=$(date -d '2016111400' +'%Y%m%d%H')` but bash informs me that that is not a valid date...

Thanks.

Comment: Convert the date to `yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:DD` format, then pass to date. `I have a list of files` - why don't you then loop through files sorted alphabetically?

Comment: Please [edit] and add a [mcve]. I'm not really clear what you want to loop over.

Comment: I have added information in order to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not *bash* telling you the date format is wrong: `date` is telling you. Not everything you type is a *bash* command.

As Kamil comments, you have to split it up so that date can parse it. The `YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS` format is parsable. Using bash [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to extract the relevant substrings:

```
$ d=2016111400
$ date -d "${d:0:4}-${d:4:2}-${d:6:2} ${d:8:2}:00:00"
Mon Nov 14 00:00:00 EST 2016
```

Now, when you want to add 12 hours, you have to be careful to do it in the right place in the datetime string: if you add a `+` character *after* the time, it will be parsed as a timezone offset, so put the relative part either first or between the date and the time.

```
$ date -d "+12 hours ${d:0:4}-${d:4:2}-${d:6:2} ${d:8:2}:00:00"
Mon Nov 14 12:00:00 EST 2016
```

As a loop, you could do:

```
d=2016111400
for ((i=1; i<=10; i++)); do
  # print this datetime
  date -d "${d:0:4}-${d:4:2}-${d:6:2} ${d:8:2}:00:00"
  # add 12 hours
  d=$( date -d "+12 hours ${d:0:4}-${d:4:2}-${d:6:2} ${d:8:2}:00:00" "+%Y%m%d%H" )
done
```

outputs:

```
Mon Nov 14 00:00:00 EST 2016
Mon Nov 14 12:00:00 EST 2016
Tue Nov 15 00:00:00 EST 2016
Tue Nov 15 12:00:00 EST 2016
Wed Nov 16 00:00:00 EST 2016
Wed Nov 16 12:00:00 EST 2016
Thu Nov 17 00:00:00 EST 2016
Thu Nov 17 12:00:00 EST 2016
Fri Nov 18 00:00:00 EST 2016
Fri Nov 18 12:00:00 EST 2016
```

---

OK, a "nicer" way to loop

```
start=2019043000
end=2019050300

plus12hours() {
  local d=$1
  date -d "+12 hours ${d:0:4}-${d:4:2}-${d:6:2} ${d:8:2}:00:00" "+%Y%m%d%H"
}

for (( d = start; d <= end; d = $(plus12hours "$d") )); do
  printf "%d\t%s\n" "$d" "$(date -d "${d:0:4}-${d:4:2}-${d:6:2} ${d:8:2}:00:00")"
done
```

```
2019043000  Tue Apr 30 00:00:00 EDT 2019
2019043012  Tue Apr 30 12:00:00 EDT 2019
2019050100  Wed May  1 00:00:00 EDT 2019
2019050112  Wed May  1 12:00:00 EDT 2019
2019050200  Thu May  2 00:00:00 EDT 2019
2019050212  Thu May  2 12:00:00 EDT 2019
2019050300  Fri May  3 00:00:00 EDT 2019
```

Comment: Thanks. I have just updated my question following some suggestions. I want to use the dates and the step of 12 hours in the for loop.

Comment: just watch out for your users' timezone: this might give you a surprising result: `TZ=America/Sao_Paulo date -d '+12 hours 2018-11-3 12:00:00'`

Comment: Thanks. My timezone is GMT. Is your solution still valid?

Comment: Yes it is. The oddity with some timezones is that they "jump forward" at midnight, so the time 00:00:00 does not exist, so you have to be prepared to catch errors.